# Programatically created a UIButton, but no click effect (text effect only)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I create a button like this, but when I click on it there's no changing effect.

```
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [button setTitle: @"xxxxx" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.98 green:0.44 blue:0.05 alpha:1] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

I'm not going to use two images, I just want the text to change a bit. Just like a fresh button dragged to the UIViewController.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set a title and a title color when the button is clicked.

```
 [button setTitle: @"clicked" forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
 [button setTitleColor: [UIColor redColor] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

See [UIControl Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_State)